# hp-health install debian 7 weezy invoke-rc.d: initscript hp-health, action "start" failed. HP Proliant G4 DL380

Tags: debian

Trying to install the deb packages on a HP Proliant G4 DL380

Setting up hp-health (9.4.0.1.7-5.) ...
  Starting Proliant System Health Monitor (hpasmd):
                [ FAILED ]

invoke-rc.d: initscript hp-health, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing hp-health (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 hp-health
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

---

The main problem now is that the fans are "screaming"
I guess it is because it can't red health staus?

Any solution to install this deb package or any other solution to stop the fans from screaming?

Answer (score 2):

No, hp-health version **9.1.0** does not but **8.7.0** does flawlessly on our 380G4. I just installed *hp-health_8.7.0.1.2-5_amd64.deb* out of the *HP_ProLiant_Value_Add_Software-8.70-10-6.iso*.

Works like a charm:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
7.7
# dpkg -l hp-health
ii  hp-health                    8.7.0.1.2-5         amd64
# hpasmcli -s "show temp"

Sensor   Location              Temp       Threshold
------   --------              ----       ---------
#1        PROCESSOR_ZONE       36C/96F    62C/143F 
#2        CPU#1                38C/100F   80C/176F 
#3        I/O_ZONE             38C/100F   60C/140F 
#4        CPU#2                 -          -       
#5        POWER_SUPPLY_BAY     31C/87F    53C/127F
```

The array tool *hpacucli-9.40* just out of the MCP repository is fine.

Comment: Following this I was able to get hp-health installed on a G4p. Has anyone got hp-snmp-agents working? I was able to instlal it, however when starting it my syslog show cmhealthd segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the Management Component Pack available from HP at: http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/project/mcp/

However, please understand that modern HP health agents don't officially support the 2005-era [ProLiant DL380 G4 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/243439/hp-proliant-dl380-g4-can-this-server-still-perform-in-2011/243441#243441) you're trying to install on. You may do better with period-correct drivers, which would have been version 8.50 on the Red Hat side. Debian wasn't officially supported by HP at the time this server was available for sale.

Try rolling back to the [earliest set of drivers](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo/mcp/pool/non-free/) available for Debian on the HP site: hp-health version 9.1.0 may work.